# Windows 8 Share Charm - how to understand if an email was sent?

Tags: c#, windows-8, charms-bar

I'm developing a Windows 8 app using C# and XAML. In the app it's possible to share stuff through email and for this I'm using the DataTransferManager to show the the share UI.

What I'm wondering is if there's any possibility to understand if the share UI was used to send an email or not? Is it possible to get some kind of response from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API doesn't provide any such response. It's up to the user to share or not share.